# This Firebase query(orderbyKey) cannot display anything

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from child("REPORTS")where datasnapshot.getRef is the same as key passed from getIntent,there is no display and I cannot tell what is wrong with code syntax

```
Intent i = getIntent();
final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey");

Query queryRef = mDatabase.child("REPORTS").equalTo(key).orderByKey();
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Log.d( "Post", "data");
    Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    if (newPost != null) {
      reportSingle = new FoodItem(newPost.get("MEAL_TITLE").toString().trim(),
      newPost.get("DESCRIPTION").toString().trim(),
      newPost.get("MEAL_INGREDIENTS").toString().trim(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to load a single report. In that case, you'll need:

```
DatabaseReference reportRef = mDatabase.child("REPORTS").child(key);
reportRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d( "Post", "data");
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
      reportSingle = new FoodItem(
        dataSnapshot.child("MEAL_TITLE").getValue(String.class).trim(),
        dataSnapshot.child("DESCRIPTION").getValue(String.class).trim(),
        dataSnapshot.child("MEAL_INGREDIENTS").getValue(String.class).trim(),
```

Comment: I am getting this bug,java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{graph.app.com.foodgraph/graph.app.com.foodgraph.MealDetailsActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://foodgraph.yyyy.com/REPORTS/-KIbgR4hDIVakm_wxEYA. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: That looks like a different error. You're passing in an invalid character for a key somewhere.

Comment: I am passing the key from a recyclerView.setOnClickListener from a classxbrew.putExtra("firekey",
                        foodList.get(position).getFireKey().toString().trim());....,so I was trying to query the child(REPORTS)where DatabaseReference key is the same as passed